# Use non persistent Preference for modifyting database data

Tags: android, android-preferences

Can I use a `Preference` with `android:persistent="false"` to modify values that are stored in a database?

**Edit: (explanation)**

The user can create any number of Foo's. Each Foo has a certain static set of properties. The properties for one Foo can be well represented by `Preference`s. But, because of the dynamic number of Foo's, `SharedPreferences` are too simple. So, I would like to use `Preference`s and write the values to a database. Is this possible or is this beyond the scope of what you can do with `Preference`?

Comment: You'll need to be a lot more specific.  I can't tell what you're trying to do.